# Installing a python script in ImageJ

Tags: python, jython, imagej

I’m trying to install a Python script in ImageJ.  My preference is to use the script with ImageJ 1.x but can use Fiji if required.

I am trying to use the script with ImageJ 1.x by placing it in the plugins folder.  The script appears in the plugins menu but when I try to run it I get an error that it can't find `__future__`

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "<string>", line 1, in <module> 
ImportError: No module named __future__
```

This makes no sense to me as the `__future__` module is being used to import the `with_statement` module and python version is listed as :

```
2.5.4rc1 (2.5:723492dbab02, Feb 8 2013, 10:13:55) 
[Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (Oracle Corporation)]
```

from `__future__ import with_statement` is specifically designed for use with Python versions 2.5.x

[https://docs.python.org/3/library/**future**.html](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__future__.html)

So ... moving on ...

I tired to use Fiji instead since it is based on ImageJ2.

I'm able to paste the code into the Script Editor using `File > New > Script ..`.

The code runs when executed from there.  However, when saved I can't get it to show up in the plugins menu.  I've tried saving it to :

`Fiji/plugins`

`Fiji/plugins/Scripts`

`Fiji/plugins/Scripts/Plugins`

The file name has an `_` in it.

The version of Fiji I'm running is 
     ImageJ 2.0.0 rc-68/1.52e / Java1.8.0_172 (64-bit)

The version of ImageJ 1.x I'm running is 
    ImageJ 1.52e / Java1.8.0_172 (64-bit)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canonical place to put scripts for ImageJ2 is `scripts/Foo/Bar/My_Script.py`, if you want it located in the menu at *Foo > Bar > My Script*.

It also works for backwards compatibility to use `plugins` or `plugins/Scripts`. However, there was recently a critical bug preventing scripts from appearing in the plugins-based locations; see [this thread](http://forum.imagej.net/t/missing-plugins-menu-item/11888). The bug is fixed in the latest release.

Comment: This worked! However, where exactly is this documented?

Comment: @Zythyr It is explained here: https://imagej.net/Scripting#Adding_scripts_to_the_Plugins_menu

Answer (score 0):

you might want to have a look here on the [ij-wiki](http://imagej.net/Introduction_into_Macro_Programming#Installing_macros). Also, there ij2 has its own, very active [forum](http://forum.imagej.net/search?q=macro%20menu%20entry) where this topic is also activeley discussed.

Best,

Felix

Comment: Posted to the imagej email listserv.  No response.

Comment: @agf1997 When posting the same question to multiple places, please disclose and cross-link, so that people can keep track of the discussion and avoid duplication of effort.